# put live audio input data into array

Tags: arrays, microphone, web-audio-api, getusermedia

Hey I am using GetUserMedia() to capture audio input from user's microphone. Meanwhile I want to put  captured values into an array so I can manipulate with them. I am using the following code but the problem is that my array gets filled with value 128 all the time (I print the results in console for now), and I can't find my mistake. Can someone help me find my mistake?

```
//create a new context for audio input
context = new webkitAudioContext();
var analyser = null;
var dataarray = [];

getLiveInput = function() {
 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true},onStream,onStreamError);
};

function onStream(stream) 
{
  var input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  var str = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(str);
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var value = str[i];

    dataarray.push(value);
    console.log(dataarray)
  }//end for loop
}//end function

function onStreamError(e) {
  console.error('Streaming failed: ', e);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values returned from `getByteTimeDomainData` are 8 bit integers, from 0 to 255. 128, which is half way, basically means "no signal". It is the equivalent of 0 in PCM audio data from -1 to 1.

But ANYWAY - there are a couple problems:

First, you're never connecting the input to the analyser. You need `input.connect(analyser)` before you call `analyser.getByteTimeDomainData()`.

The second problem isn't with your code so much as it's just an implementation issue.

Basically, the `gotStream` function only gets called once - and `getByteTimeDomainData` only returns data for 1024 samples worth of audio (a tiny fraction of a second). The problem is, this all happens *so quickly* and for *such a short period of time* after the stream gets created, that there's no real input yet. Try wrapping the `analyser.getByteTimeDomainData()` call and the loop that follows it in a 1000ms `setTimeout` and then whistle into your microphone as soon as you give the browser permission to record. You should see some values other than 128.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/avasav/5/edit

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Yes indeed I forget to connect the input with analyzer :(. The problem is then when I am using your code there is a time when array stops to get filled. How can I make it collect my values all the time?